# Jquery UI date picker kicks users off page if they hit backspace in IE

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jqueryUI for a datepicker to pick birthdays.  Turns out in IE if the person tries to type in the box instead of using the picker, and hits the backspace, they get kicked off the form and to a previous page.  Can anyone explain or propose a fix?  Also not sure why the red asterisk is showing up inside the box when it shows outside in firefox and when all the others display correctly.

Looking at the eighth field:
http://www.craftonhills.edu/Degrees_and_Certs/Divs_and_Depts/Career_Education_and_Human_Development/Public_Safety_and_Services/Fire_Technology/Firefighter_Academy/Firefighter_Academy_Info/Application

Answer (score 1):

Backspace key in the browser defaults to triggering the Back button. You can try to intercept the keystroke (See here: [Intercepting all key presses with jQuery before they are processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355594/intercepting-all-key-presses-with-jquery-before-they-are-processed)) to stop it from firing, but a better solution might be to add a "Clear" button to the jQuery UI Element to remove the field so the back button still works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $(document)
 .on('keypress keydown keyup', '.datepicker', function(e) {
       if ( e.keyCode == 8 ) e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Replace `.datepicker` with whatever selector you are using.

This should allow the backspace to work as expected in the text block but still prevent the backspace (from bubbling up the DOM) from triggering the browser back action.