# Intercept input entering

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to intercept the value the user inputs before it ever even appears in the element? I tried to use `Object.defineProperty` but it appears to not work for `InputElement.value` since

```
var value;
Object.defineProperty($('input')[0], 'value', {
    get: function() {return value},
    set: function(val) {console.log(val); value = val;}
});
```

doesn't appear to change any behavior. Or is oninput/onchange the only option? Since I'd rather have my code executes before the browser's.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpmu1xcu/

Comment: Why not just use an `oninput` or `onchange` event?

Comment: If JS is executing slowly for whatever reason, the value will be bad value for a short time before the handler fires.

Comment: Is this relevant to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355594/intercepting-all-key-presses-with-jquery-before-they-are-processed

Comment: I think `keyup` is the only option...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect input before the text is entered by the browser, you can use the [`Element.onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) property. This event fires as soon as the key is pressed down, before the browser interprets the action.

```js
var demo_i = document.getElementById('demo_i');
var demo_d = document.getElementById('demo_d');

demo_i.onkeydown = function(e) {
    demo_d.textContent = e.which;
    // Returning false stops the event from going any further
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="demo_i"><div id="demo_d"></div>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for Paste.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```js
function InterceptInputValue($input) {
  var value = $input.val();
  // intercept value that changes and saved to value variable
  $input.keydown(function(e) {
    value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    return false;
  });

  this.getValue = function() {
    return value;
  };
}

var i = new InterceptInputValue($("input"));

$("input").blur(function() {
  alert('input value is: ' + i.getValue());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only option is `keyup`.

It is the only one that can capture the data and not leave any behind.

Using the snippet below, type **test** in each of the text boxes.
The code *tries* to reset the value to blank with each key stroke.

`keyup` is the only one that deletes the input with each stroke.

`keydown` clears the last character typed, once you leave the field.

`keypress` leaves the last character typed in the `input` field

```js
var tbxKeyDown = document.getElementById('tbxKeyDown');
var tbxKeyUp = document.getElementById('tbxKeyUp');
var tbxKeyPress = document.getElementById('tbxKeyPress');

// [Jedi mind trick] ==> you entered nothing

tbxKeyDown.addEventListener('keydown', testKeyDown, false);
tbxKeyUp.addEventListener('keyup', testKeyUp, false);
tbxKeyPress.addEventListener('keypress', testKeyPress, false);

// Remove anything entered

function testKeyDown() {
  tbxKeyDown.value = '';
}

function testKeyPress() {
  tbxKeyPress.value = '';
}

function testKeyUp() {
  tbxKeyUp.value = '';
}
```

```html
KeyDown  = <input type="text" id="tbxKeyDown"  value="" />

<br/><br/>

KeyUp    = <input type="text" id="tbxKeyUp"    value="" />

<br/><br/>

KeyPress = <input type="text" id="tbxKeyPress" value="" />
```

Comment: FYI: [onKeyPress Vs. onKeyUp and onKeyDown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396754/onkeypress-vs-onkeyup-and-onkeydown)